# C# How to save my data into appdata settings folder?

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, appdata

My application saves its settings in

```
appadata\local\app\app.vshost.exe_Url_kukexgajlycv5ljlunm2odhmeuhaytc4
```

How can i get this directory so i can save in there my other data too? 
Is this a proper way or i should save them in another directory using guid?

Comment: Related question: [Accessing App.exe.config File in Special Folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501036/accessing-app-exe-config-file-in-special-folders)

Comment: This Q&A might have the answer (second answer): Where are the [Properties.Default.Settings stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982354/where-are-the-properties-default-settings-stored). I haven't tried it myself, but check it out.

Comment: i checked. Its not possible to get that directory so i will stick with a guid folder. ty

Comment: Another question that mentions the same thing and might have the answer: [How to get application settings path in winforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291821/how-to-get-application-settings-path-in-winforms)